# Log file name based on application with syslog-ng

Tags: linux, logging, syslog

I'm using syslog-ng and currently my config only separates log files based on ip address and facility:

```
source s_network_udp {
  syslog(transport(udp) port(514));
};

destination d_local {
  file("/var/log/${HOST}/${FACILITY}.log" create_dirs(yes));
};

log {
  source(s_network_udp);
  destination(d_local);
};
```

this gives me this:

```
./0.0.0.1/daemon.log
./0.0.0.1/user.log
./0.0.0.1/kern.log
./0.0.0.2/daemon.log
./0.0.0.2/user.log
./0.0.0.2/kern.log
./0.0.0.3/daemon.log
./0.0.0.3/user.log
./0.0.0.3/kern.log
./0.0.0.4/daemon.log
./0.0.0.4/user.log
./0.0.0.4/kern.log
```

The `daemon.log` files have lines like this:

```
Sep  2 23:19:33 hostname systemd-resolved[1290]: etc
Sep  2 23:20:01 hostname CRON[2342925]: etc
Sep  2 23:20:01 hostname CRON[2342924]: etc2
```

Is there a way to have syslog-ng make a file for every `process[1]:` instead of just daemon,user,kern ?